# ¿Cómo puedo llevar una base de datos SQL server versión 20.19 a SQL server versión 20.16?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola un gusto estoy con es duda será posible hacer ese cambio he estado buscando información pero hay muy poca alguien que haya realizado, podría darme una mano con esta solución porfavor.

Muchísimas gracias saludos cordiales

Comment: Tienes una instalación en 2019 y le quieres hacer downgrade a 2016? Es claro que vas a perder funcionalidades? Ahí la fácil es hacer backup de las BD que tengas y ver si se pueden importar en una 2016 de prueba... luego sacar los backups completos, desinstalar e instalar 2016

Comment: **Por qué quieres hacerlo?** Existe una sentencia, un sistema, un inconveniente que surgió en la versión 20.19 que no está en la 20.16? Además, como Alfabravo pregunta, estás hablando de 2019/2016? porque esos build numbers (20.19 20.16) no existen.

Comment: Hola que tal un gusto, muchas gracias por los comentarios, la pregunta es que quiero pasarla del sql server 2019 al 2016, lo que pasa es que en mi trabajo quiere realizar este proceso ya que un banco con el trabajan no puede subir de version de sql son cosas administrativas así que nos toca pasar la base del 2019 al 2016

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pides es algo que en teoría no se puede hacer. La compatibilidad de las bases de datos es solo retroactiva. Lo que significa que las versiones más nuevas pueden identificar las versiones más antiguas, pero no funciona a la inversa.

Lo que puedes hacer, y es un proceso propenso a errores y mucho esfuerzo, es generar los scripts de estructura y datos de la base de datos. Ten en cuenta, que si el tamaño de la base de datos es muy grande, el archivo quedará demasiado grande para poder abrirlo y editarlo con programas comunes. Solo queda poder ejecutarlo directamente y rezar por que funcione y no se hayan implementado funciones que no estén disponibles en la versión anterior.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu comentario, claro tienes razón lo que dices, pero por razones administrativas nos toca hacer este proceso y para que tocara realizar mediante script